# Integral rational trigonometric function, what I did wrong?

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometric-integrals

I would like if someone can tell me what I did wrong. I have the integral : $$\int \frac{dx}{(2+cosx)sinx}$$

This is my solution:

$\begin{align}\int \frac{dx}{(2+cosx)sinx} = \int \frac{dx}{2sinx +sinxcosx}= \text{  substitude  
  } u=tan\frac{x}{2} \longrightarrow cosx=\frac{1-u^2}{1+u^2}\space {sinx=}\frac{2u}{1+u^2} \quad dx= \frac{2}{1+u^2}du \rightarrow\end{align}$

$\begin{align} \int\frac{1}{\frac{4u}{1+u^2}+\frac{2u}{1+u^2}\frac{1-u^2}{1+u^2}}\cdot\frac{2du}{(1+u^2)} 
 =\int\frac{1+u^2}{u(3-u^2)} = \frac{1}{3}\int(\frac{1}{u}+\frac{1}{\sqrt3+u}+\frac{1}{\sqrt3-u})du \end{align}$  $$\frac{1}{3}(\ln|{u}| -\ln|\sqrt3+u|\ln|\sqrt3-u|)+c$$

and than I change back to x variable and get : $$ \frac{1}{3}(\ln|{\tan\frac{x}{2}}| -\ln|\sqrt3+\tan\frac{x}{2}|\ln|\sqrt3-\tan\frac{x}{2}|)+c$$

And that's not the right answer when I check on internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think where you have $u(3-u^2)$ in the denominator of an integrand, it should be $u(3+u^2)$.  Indeed, $$
4u(1+u^2)+2u(1-u^2)=4u+4u^3+2u-2u^3=6u+2u^3=2u(3+u^2)$$

Comment: true buddy, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Here I provide you another way to approach it just for the sake of comparison.

To begin with, notice that we can rewrite the integrand as

\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{(2+\cos(x))\sin(x)} & = \frac{2 + \cos(x)}{(2+\cos(x))\sin(x)} - \frac{1+\cos(x)}{(2+\cos(x))\sin(x)}\\\\
& = \frac{1}{\sin(x)} - \frac{1-\cos^{2}(x)}{(2+\cos(x))(1-\cos(x))\sin(x)}\\\\
& = \frac{1}{\sin(x)} - \frac{\sin(x)}{(2+\cos(x))(1-\cos(x))}
\end{align*}

The first term is easy to integrate and the second can be integrated according to the substitution $u = \cos(x)$.

Indeed, one has that
\begin{align*}
-\int\frac{\sin(x)}{(2+\cos(x))(1-\cos(x))}\mathrm{d}x= \int\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{(2+u)(1-u)}
\end{align*}

Since we have that
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{(2+u)(1-u)} & = \frac{1}{3}\times\frac{3}{(2+u)(1-u)} = \frac{1}{3}\times\frac{(2 + u) + (1 - u)}{(2+u)(1-u)} = \frac{1}{3(1-u)} + \frac{1}{3(2+u)}
\end{align*}

Thus we have that
\begin{align*}
-\int\frac{\sin(x)}{(2+\cos(x))(1-\cos(x))}\mathrm{d}x = \frac{\ln|1-\cos(x)| + \ln|2+\cos(x)|}{3} + c
\end{align*}

as well as
\begin{align*}
\int\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\sin(x)} = -\ln|\cot(x) + \csc(x)|
\end{align*}

and we are done.

Comment: can you explain how you got to the second term in the second line? $\frac{\sin(x)}{(2+\cos(x))(1-\cos(x))}$

Comment: Sure. I have edited my answer. Notice that $1-\cos^{2}(x) = \sin^{2}(x)$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: yes I got it, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Hint

Another way

$$\int\dfrac{dx}{(a+\cos x)\sin x}$$

$$=\int\dfrac{\sin x}{(a+\cos x)(1-\cos x)(1+\cos x)}dx$$

Let $\cos x=y$

then https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PartialFractionDecomposition.html

and https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_substitution#The_substitution